# Grid / ruler toggle button at top of photoshop missing in CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids

In Photoshop CS5 there was a button at the top bar of the program where you could toggle rulers / grids (it was a square button and the had a ruler-looking border). I'd like to know how I can get this to show in CS6.

What I'm talking about:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: As a new user of CS6, it's very irritating that PS does not provide a starter manual. In particular they should provide a list of keyboard shortcuts, especially that these are now the only way of accessing some features. Maybe I missed something obvious somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find it either. So they either moved it into oblivion or they just got rid of it.

I would recommend the hotkeys/shortcuts:

<kbd>CTRL + '</kbd> = Toggle grid

<kbd>CTRL + R</kbd> = Toggle rulers

These are much faster than moving the mouse around and pressing buttons anyways!

Comment: It's true. It fell off into the bit bucket when they were building the new UI, and nobody could find it. :) I've always used Ctl-R, so I never missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it at the View menu (along with rulers, grid, snap to, etc.)

Comment: Well none of those work for me. when I clicked view and clicked rulers, the rulers still do not appear.

Answer (score -3):

Rulers and grids are in the View Panel. 
Rulers are directly in view panel and and grid is hidden in show.
Hope this helps

Comment: View panel?? No such thing in any version of Photoshop I have.